# css last-child just before ending tag

Tags: css

how can I select a last-child only if it is just before an ending tag ?

select the last br

```
<p>efwegerger<br />wegregeqr<br /></p>
```

but not the last one in that case

```
<p>efwegerger<br />wegregeqr<br />dfbbgbgrbr</p>
```

thank you

Comment: This isn't possible using pure CSS

Comment: CSS only sees tags in the tree , both example are the same. If you can style :first-letter or :first-line that's about what you can do with text.

Comment: What is the purpose, cause it should not be a trouble ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKbJBq is it ?

Comment: You can only do this in firefox using [`br:last-of-type:-moz-last-node`](https://jsfiddle.net/w08wn091/1/)  but it is non-standard css  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-last-node